# Black tiny shapes in chat's input textbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

If a user expands the chatbox's height, this occurs:

[image]

Not the only one who managed to reproduce this bug. Using Chrome 23.0.1271.97 on Windows 8 x64.

Comment: I get this bug also in Win 7 x64 on Chrome  24.0.1312.45. See: http://snag.gy/dnQdw.jpg

Comment: Same here, Win7x64 Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 m

Comment: Confirmed. This does not happen in **Opera**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an issue of non-matching heights between the textarea and the CSS. On the element itself, a height of 58px is specified (which becomes 62px with the padding added in), which is *exactly* the height of the section being used in the [sprite image](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/Img/sprites.png). However, the CSS specifies a `max-height: 60px` which allows you to resize the textarea 2 extra pixels higher than should be allowed. Doing so, the tip of the right-pointing arrow below the sprite section being used gets repeated horizontally with the gradient.

> [image: Sprite Image]

It should show on all browsers which properly implemented everything. If not, you probably have the sprite image blocked or something, or your browser sucks.

Anyways, having the same max-height in the CSS as the inline height so you can't expand it vertically seems like the intended behavior. Simple enough fix. :P

Comment: We could just get rid of the sprite. These days all browsers support `box-shadow` via CSS, so going with an image isn't really necessary anymore. Well, or we could just disable resizing the box :)

Answer (score 5):

I have just removed the background image for the next build. It's 2013; there's no reason to use an image to give the box a subtle inset box shadow anymore.

Comment: But you removed the max-height? Now the textarea can be expanded down past the visible area. o.o

Comment: I didn't remove any max-height.